# How to intercept a phone number click (Call button) on link in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate, datadetectortypes

Is there a callback to identify when the user clicks **Call** in the Popup that comes when we click on a number in a textview?

`func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool`

The function mentioned above will help me identify that a link has been clicked in a UITextView, Whereas is there a specific callback to identify if **Call** is clicked or **Cancel** is clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the delegate method:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        print("Phone \(URL)")
        return false
}
```

don't forget to connect the textView delegate.

```
self.textView.delegate = self
```

Then you can add a custom UIAlertController to call or cancel.

Edit:

This is the full code:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

    if (URL.scheme == "tel"){
        let phoneNumber = URL.absoluteString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("tel:", withString: "")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: phoneNumber, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .Default, handler: { (alert) in
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(URL) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(URL)
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (alert) in
            print("User Canceld")
        }))
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

One last thing,, in your info.plist add:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>tel</string>
</array>
```